# Application variable refresh in an mvc web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Application level variable that gets loaded from a database when the application starts. Now when accessing the variable, I check to see if it is not null. If it is not null I use it, if it is null I initialize it from the database, then use it.

My question is how can I make sure that this variable is refreshed atleast once a day? Is there something in .net or the MVC framework to help with this?

Does IIS unload an application if it has not accessed for a while? If so then my variable would be refreshed each time the app is reloaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the class [System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) to store the variable with an expiration time. That way once a day is up the value will be cleared and your code could reload it from the DB.